# EXC_BAD_ACCESS - NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have a class that uses NSURLConnection to fire a POST request.

I have other classes use a delegate on this class that it uses to fire an event when a response has been received.

When I've parsed the response, I call the delegate like so:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)conn { ...
            if (delegate)
            {
                [delegate serverDataLayerResponse:entity];
            } ... }
```

I'm getting "EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address-..." on the line inside the if block.

I've even tried @try and @catch around that part but it stills kills my app.

I'm suspecting that the delegate is still pointing to as object in memory that has been released? How can I guard from this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Keep a strong/retain reference to it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a bad pointer. `delegate` is nonzero, so the test passes, but doesn't point to a valid object. You could put a breakpoint in the delegate's `-dealloc` to detect whether the object was deallocated. Also, try breaking where you assign the delegate and make sue you've got a valid object at that point.